# Jolt Spec for Json value "DE000001000150084063368" with substring if string is dynamic

Tags: json, jolt

Below is my input

```
[
  {
    "correlationId": "12345",
    "payloadFormat": "Money",
    "payload": {
      "DE61": "000001000150084063368456"
     
    }
  },
  {
    "correlationId": "ed1e3",
    "payloadFormat": "Cash",
    "payload": {
      "DE61": "000001000150084063368"
     
    }
  }
]
```

Expected output is

```
[ {
  "payload" : {
    "correlationId" : "12345",
    "payloadFormat" : "Money",
    "DE61SF1" : "00",
    "DE61SF2" : "100015008",
    "DE61SF3" : "4063368",
    "DE61SF4" : "456"
    
  }
}, {
  "payload" : {
    "correlationId" : "ed1e3",
    "payloadFormat" : "Cash",
    "DE61SF1" : "00",
    "DE61SF2" : "100015008",
    "DE61SF3" : "4063368",
    "DE61SF4" : "null"
   
   
  }
} ]
```

I am using below jolt spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "&",
        // Shift all the DE nodes to a same named node.
        // Here it is moved as TMPDE
        "payload": {
          "DE|DE61": "&2.payload.TMPDE"
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "payload": {
          "DE61SF1": "=substring(@(1,TMPDE), 2, 4)",
          "DE61SF2": "=substring(@(1,TMPDE), 5, 14)",
          "DE61SF3": "=substring(@(1,TMPDE), 14, 21)",
          "DE61SF4": "=substring(@(1,TMPDE), 21, 24)"
        }
      }
    }
  },

   {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "correlationId": "[&1].payload.correlationId",
        "payloadFormat": "[&1].payload.payloadFormat",
        "payload": {
          "DE61SF1": "[&2].payload.DE61SF1",
          "DE61SF2": "[&2].payload.DE61SF2",
          "DE61SF3": "[&2].payload.DE61SF3",
          "DE61SF4": "[&2].payload.DE61SF4",
         
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But if my fourth substring has no value then that value is not printing.
My requirements is that if in input the string has not enough value then while split if no value comes, then for that element it should show as null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below spec at the end of your spec, this helps

```
{
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "payload": {
          "DE61SF4": "null"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Jagadesh, I have to put null depending upon the value I received in Json input, if we have the value it should populate value , other wise put null for those keys

Comment: Yes, if you add the above spec, it will put the value for DE61SF4, if input json has value, otherwise it will put null. You can add if this is needed for other values also.

Comment: Thanks Jagadesh for quick reply, actually this I have to decide at runtime, if value is available then it should populate as per substring and if value is not come then for those key null should assign to those key.

Comment: Yes, the above will work.. Try running the spec, so you that you can understand much better.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jagadesh, you are really great, its works wonder.